# How to upload file through api like pdf/doc/image/xls using expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Hello everyone I am using expo to build an app. I am using document picker to upload any kind of file. Problem is to upload file other than Image. I convert image to base64 and successfully upload but other files return me error. Any help how to do so?

Below is my code

```
async selectMultipleFile() {

let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ type: "*/*",copyToCacheDirectory: true }).then(response => {
  console.log(response, '..........')
  if (response.type == 'success') {
    let options = { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 };
    const bs = FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(response.uri,options).then(data => {
      // const base64 = 'data:image/jpg;base64' + data;
      this.setState({
        file : data
      })
      console.log(data, '..........')
    });

    delete response['type'];
    // console.log(response, '..........',bs)
    let type = response.name.split('.');
    // console.log(type);
    response.type = type[1];
    this.setState({ extension: type });
  }
  // console.log(this.state.file, '...............file')

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ type: "*/*", copyToCacheDirectory: true }).then(response => {

  if (response.type == 'success') {

    let { name, size, uri } = response;
    let nameParts = name.split('.');
    let fileType = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];
    var fileToUpload = {
      name: name,
      size: size,
      uri: uri,
      type: "application/" + fileType
    };
    console.log(fileToUpload, '...............file')
    this.setState({ file: fileToUpload });
  }


});
```